# escaped characters in write() in C

Tags: c, buffer, overwrite

it seems that escaped characters passed in write() don't work (at least) properly.

```
printf("test");
printf("\r1234);
```

return

```
123
```

as expected, but

```
printf("test");
write(1, "\r1234, 5);
```

return

```
1234test
```

so the line is not overwritten

I would like to know how to erase/overwrite a line in C (i am on linux btw)
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7594163/13422

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19757937/13422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing the output stream:
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test");
    fflush(stdout);
    write(1, "\r1234", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Comment: a significant part of the problem is failing to include the appropriate header file for the system function 'write()'  which for linux would be '#include <unistd.h>'

Comment: haha thanks, but couldn't you just have said "you forgot to include unistd.h"?

Answer (score 2):

Your *REAL* problem is that `printf` is buffered and `write` is immediate. And so the write goes first. Yes it does send the `\r`, the terminal reads it and moves to the front of the line. And when the program exits it flushes the STDOUT buffer and prints the printf contents.

Comment: thank you,I didn't know about this difference, but what is I have an infinite loop with printf ? it flushes the STDOUT each loop, right ? so printf also flushes stdout for the previous printf executed ?

Comment: @lokoum Why would you believe that printf flushes the buffer? In fact, printf and other buffered IO functions are only guaranteed to flush the buffer when flush/fflush is called or when the program exits.

Comment: you can force a buffer output/flush by having the last two characters on the format parameter for the printf() be: '\n'

Comment: User3629249: That is the line buffering mode which does not apply to disk files or Windows consoles.